# Is technically valid a positiveInteger restriction with maxInclusive 9999999999?

Tags: xsd

I'm working with a web service from an external company, which has defined the following restriction to an element in their wsdl:

```
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Doing the conversion of this restriction in a class, I created a property with the tipe UInt32, but this data type only allows numbers up to 4294967295, very lower than the maxInclusive defined in the restriction.

This kind of restriction is technically and logicaly valid for a schema? or is wrong and the external company should change the base type to a bigger one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction is fine. Have a look at the [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#positiveInteger).

> [Definition:]   positiveInteger is ·derived· from nonNegativeInteger by setting the value of ·minInclusive· to be 1.  This results in the standard mathematical concept of the positive integer numbers.  The ·value space· of positiveInteger is the **infinite set** {1,2,...}.  The ·base type· of positiveInteger is nonNegativeInteger.

What they probably mean this value to be is an xs:unsignedInt or xs:unsignedLong, but technically its correct.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed my conversion to Decimal type, following the mapping specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/mapping-xml-data-types-to-clr-types